# Error While Debug Project In Android Studio , Error : app:mergeDebugResources Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I made an Android App. However, when I try to debug my app, I get a Gradle error. I tried re-running the app, but it doesn’t work. I have used Kotlin for making the app. My error:

```
error : 
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

A failure occurred while executing 
     com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
        
Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
```

Module Gradle File :

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
     }

    android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lordshivaproduct.commenting_FROM_SHIVAN"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        …
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        …
    }
    composeOptions {
        
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.0-beta01"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    }

    dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
    }
```

My question might be similar to others, but the other questions on Stack Overflow don’t solve my problem.

Image of Terminal :
[MINGW64 Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcLpM.png)

Image Of Stacktrace:
[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1loAq.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post your `build.gradle` files for us to understand the problem here. Please look at [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand what info should be there in a question to get help.

Comment: I made a Change Can You Look Into it To Know If i am correctly edited

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post the relevant Build Output logs as shown [here in this image](https://developer.android.com/static/studio/images/run/build_output_window_error-2x.png)?

Comment: As i am facing slowness i am using MINGW64 terminal to Debug so that  ill share that screenshot

Comment: Great! Can you please run the gradle command with `--stacktrace` flag to get the detailed exception message? Or you could just run it in the Android Studio as shown in the image link in my previous comment.

Comment: I added ScreenShot of Stacktrace

Comment: Right! You are probably using `tools:context` attribute in any of your **layout xml** files or the **AndroidManifest.xml** file. If you are, then you need to import the _namespace_ as `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in order to use the `tools:context` attribute.

Comment: yes absolutely I did that and it's working fine. Please add your comment as answer so I could select that as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using `tools:context` attribute in any of your **layout xml** files or the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

If you are, then you need to import the *namespace* as `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in order to use the `tools:context` attribute.